# Tw-Bootstrap Tab-Dropdown item not being accesible when created on the fly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `tab` with two `dropdowns`, one of them is created on the fly.
Code after render.

```
<ul id="tabOp" class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="" role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#global" aria-expanded="false">Global</a></li>
<li id="liDropdownCentro" role="presentation" class="dropdown active">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#centro" aria-expanded="false">Centro
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul id="dropdownCentroList" class="dropdown-menu"><li class="active"><a href="#ddc1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Option 1</a></li><li><a href="#ddc2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Option 2</a></li></ul>
</li>
<li id="liDropdownSupervisor" class="dropdown" role="presentation">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#supervisor" aria-expanded="false">Supervisor
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul id="dropdownSupervisorList" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class=""><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Submenu 1-2</a></li>                                
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now I want to react when the users selects an option from those `dropdowns`.

```
$('.dropdown-menu > li').on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this));        
});
```

The hardcoded `dropdown` reacts, but the one created on the fly doesn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since you are adding elements dynamically, you have to bind the click event to the document since the added elements do not exist when the document is ready try:

```
$(document).on('click','.dropdown-menu > li', function () {
    console.log($(this));        
});
```

Comment: Didn't know that, thought that `.on('click',` was enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery feature of `.change()` is what you would want to call:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').change(()=>{
    console.log($(this));
})
```

This will be called whenever the dropdown is changed(eg: option is clicked)

The reason that your solution will not work is because on load time, the JQuery `.on()` function is applied to all current `<li>` elements, but the `.change()` is applied directly to the parent.

Comment: It's not reacting, nothing in the console. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate the event to the **tabOp** because the child element does not exist when you attach the event handler.

In the following snippet an example:

```js
var strHTML = '    <li id="liDropdownSupervisor" class="dropdown" role="presentation">\
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#supervisor" aria-expanded="false">Supervisor\
        <span class="caret"></span>\
        </a>\
        <ul id="dropdownSupervisorList" class="dropdown-menu">\
        <li class=""><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Submenu 1-1</a></li>\
<li class=""><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Submenu 1-2</a></li>\
</ul>\
</li>\
';

$('#tabOp').on('click', '.dropdown-menu > li', function () {
    console.log(this.outerHTML);
});


//
// add item on the fly 
//
$('#tabOp').append(strHTML);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul id="tabOp" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="" role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#global" aria-expanded="false">Global</a></li>
    <li id="liDropdownCentro" role="presentation" class="dropdown active">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#centro" aria-expanded="false">Centro
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul id="dropdownCentroList" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#ddc1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ddc2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I thought of it at the beginning but decided to look for a quicker fix. Thank you!